# "Type or namespace name *name* cannot be found" Error only in method declarations

Tags: c#, namespaces

I am getting a "Type or namespace name *name* cannot be found" error, **but only in the method declarations, and only on two specific object types**:

```
 public List<Transit> GetStops() //This throws error
 {
      List<Transit> stops = new List<Transit>(); //This does not throw error
```

If I try to access `Transit` through the `Path.To.Namespace.Transit` in the method declaration, I still get the error. Visual Studio 2012 can find the class in the auto suggestions both in the method declaration, and below it (Before I try to build again). Something like the code below will throw no errors:

```
 public List<string> GetStops() 
 {
      List<Transit> stops = new List<Transit>(); //No Error
```

This occurs for only 2 classes located in that namespace.

```
public Stop GetCurrentStop() //Error
{
   Stop stop = new Stop(); // No Error
```

The rest of the classes in that namespace will not throw this error. **Both classes are public and only contain a constructor.** Visual Studio will list both objects as suggestions, and will map them to the correct namespace in the code below the method declaration.

Here is an example of the one of the classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Path.To.Namespace
{
    public class Transit
    {
        public string Id {  get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Travel Mode {get; private set;} //Class in same namespace
        public Location StopPoint { get; private set; } //Class in same namespace

        public Transit(string id, string name, Travel mode, Location stopPoint)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Mode = mode;
            StopPoint = stopPoint;
         }
    }
}
```

The other one is the very similar, just with different object types. And restarting my PC/VS did not solve the issue

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? :) Seriously though.. sounds like something has gone sideways IDE/compiler wise. A PC reboot/restart of VS may help.

Comment: Can you show us a [short, complete](http://sscce.org/) example of the problem? I'm with @SimonWhitehead: it looks like something wonky with VS, not your code.

Comment: Does the Transit class involve generics at all? If so, please post the code definition.

Comment: Posted the class in the edits

Comment: Is it in a different assembly?

Comment: It appears to be. Both classes are in the same project as other classes referenced in this code (Travel, Location). This was a project that was created on VS2010, and I am using VS2012. Build settings are the same between the projects as well

Comment: The issue was caused by a SVN branching issue. The .csproj file was referencing a different branch through it's file path. Fixing that fixed this issue